# FullCalendar locale month names not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I was trying to use 'locale: is' option in FullCalendar and I saw that in the demo: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale-demo the 'is' option was not displaying the month names right in Google Chrome.[Demo in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lypmL.png)

But works correctly in Firefox.[Demo in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhbiU.png) (and also works in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer)

Its only the month names that isn't being translated. Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: usually, if you change the local of momentJs aswel, it works.

Comment: It is not changing in firefox either, atleast not by the screen that you show, it just shows a different text than in chrome, but if you go to the console and check "window.FullCalendarLocalesAll" you will see that the Month word for IS is not "nóvember". So ye it is not working, but not only in chrome

Comment: did you tried chrome incognito mode ?

Comment: @SunilKumar Yes, it did not work.

Comment: Please put your code here, how you work with full calendar js.

Comment: @Nicolas I tried to do that in codepen.io by adding 'moment.locale('is');' but that did not work. https://codepen.io/alexinn/pen/eYYMpVY?&editable=true&editors=001

Comment: @Nicolas fullCalendar v4 does not use momentJS

Comment: @SunilKumar It is similar to the code for the demo but my problem is that the 'locale' option is only working on other browsers but not Google Chrome.

Comment: @Alex I don't think there is much you can do about this, it's all down to which locales each individual browser's JS engine supports in the Date object. fullCalendar just uses whatever the Date object returns. standalone demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5sozurLk/ I would complain to the Chrome / Chromium project if I was you

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, I will try that